# How to add print button which is use to directly print report instead pressing ctrl+shift+p in odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, odoo-10

I am working on printing report where report first download or directly press ctrl+hift+p to print. How can i add button which directly print report instead pressing ctrl+shift+p?

Answer (score 5):

Create a Button in form view.

```xml
<button type="object" name="print_report" />
```

On click of button call this method.

```py
@api.multi
def print_report(self):
   return self.env['report'].get_action(self,'MODULE_NAME.REPORT_NAME')
```

Make sure you are having a report with `name="MODULE_NAME.REPORT_NAME"`.